# SignalR invoke not working due to an error on the server

Tags: unity-game-engine, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am developing a VR game on Unity, SignalR is working with all the methods in my Hub.

The problem is that one method is not working as expected. The method should return some info about the game at the end of the game but I get this error:

`Failed to invoke 'SessionReport' due to an error on the server.`

But if I try to call the method at the start of the game it works as expected.

Here's the code in Unity used to Invoke my method 'SessionReport'.

```cs
public async static void SendReportInfo()
{
    HubConnection hubConnection = SignalRInitConnection.hubConnection;
    if (hubConnection != null && hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        Debug.Log("SignalR: Method SendReportInfo invoked");
        try
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SessionReport", MapStats.riskHistory, MapStats.scoreHistory, MapStats.envHistory, MapStats.difficultyLvlByEnv, MapStats.mapNameByEnv);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("EXCEPTION SESSION REPORT:" + e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("SignalR: hubCon is ko for SendReportInfo");
    }
}
```

Here's the method in my SignalR Hub:

```cs
public void SessionReport(List<List<Risk>> riskHistory, List<int> scoreHistory, List<int> envHistory, List<int> difficultyLvlByEnv, List<string> mapNameByEnv)
{
    //Insert into DB
    Console.WriteLine("Nice session report there.");
}
```

The connection to the Hub is still established when I invoke the 'SessionReport' method at the end of the game.

Why is the method 'SessionReport' working at the start of the game but not at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the class Risk on the server didn't have a default constructor. Without the constructor SignalR can't copy what's sent from Unity to an object on the server.